# Failed to call a property of type Collection in a Table using SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I can not get the data of a `BusinessPartners` property of the collection type.
In the EntitySet `BusinessPartners` is the `BPAddresses` property of the Collection Type, which I want to show all the addresses of that collection in a `<Table>` control, but the console gives me the following error

> Failed to get contexts for
>   /destinations/******/BusinessPartners('1022')/ContactEmployees with
>   start index 0 and length 100 - TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'length' of undefined

**Property**

```
<Property Name="BPAddresses" Type="Collection(SAPB1.BPAddress)"/>
```

**The Request works and shows the contacts**

```
https://*******/BusinessPartners('C000001')/ContactEmployees?$orderby=CardCode&$skip=0&$top=100
```

**VIEW**

```
<Table items = "{ path: 'ContactEmployees',
  sorter: { path: 'CardCode' }
} ">
```

Comment: Did you checked /IWFND/error_log ? Also check if the length is defined properly in SEGW attributes

Comment: Do you have a bindElement call somewhere in your code for the BusinessPartner entity?

Comment: Thank you already solved, just add the expand in the view controller details

Comment: @Json Please add the solution as an answer and accept it to inform others that this issue is resolved.